# Printing number of words in paragraph

Tags: java, data-structures, bufferedreader, eof

I am taking user input in the form of paragraph and I have to count the words in the paragraph until `EOF` paragraph. User will not input "Quit/stop" keywords from console but just the `EOF` paragraph. I am not getting the desired output.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CountWords 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);
    
            int wordCount = 1;
            String str;
            while ((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
               str = br.readLine();
    
             for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
             {
                if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
                {
                    wordCount++;
                } 
             }
            System.out.println(wordCount);
           }
   
        }
    }
```

Sample input:-

```
This is a sample line of text
This is another line of text
This line is the 3rd line
This junk line contains 989902 99dsaWjJ8            015
This is the fifth and the last line of input

Output: 36
```

Comment: You are skipping half the lines. The while loop will start by evaluating the condition, which will execute `str = br.readLine()` and if str is not null, it will execute `str = br.readLine()` and therefore ignore the first line, and every 2nd line after

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without defining what is 'word' or 'paragraph'.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo paragraph will be give as user input & i want to count the number of words in that paragraph. I have given sample i/o

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the comment about removing the duplicated **str = br.readLine()** is completely valid, but still the program will not work correctly. Because the bellow statement, first words in the lines will be ignored and not counted (a line doesn't necessarly begin with a space):

```
if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
```

It's also not possible that your program just reads a parapraph and stops, because it's designed to always wait for the next line. How about stopping when you hit additional enter after pasting the input?

Anyway, this version should work better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);

    int wordCount = 0;
    String str;
    while (!(str = br.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
        wordCount += Arrays.stream(str.split("\\s+")).filter(word -> !word.isEmpty()).count();
    }
    System.out.println(wordCount);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using your code and it's fine removing this single line:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);
    
            int wordCount = 1;
            String str;
            while ((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
              // str = br.readLine();
    
             for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
             {
                if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
                {
                    wordCount++;
                } 
             }
            System.out.println(wordCount);
           }
   
        }
```

You are already reading the line in the while sentence mate, so it was reading it twice

Comment: But this will read a single line only.I want to read the paragraph..